# Не могу заставить чат-бота определять команду в строке

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Может кто-то подскажет. Делаю чат бота, его суть: если кто-то из пользователей в групповом чате отправляет сообщение и в нем содержется ключевое слово, то бот отправляет прикольный войс. Получилось сделать так, что бот работает только в том случае если ключевое слово отправлено отдельным сообщением, а как сделать так чтоб он распознавал команду в предложении.
Например : Всем привет друзья! ключевое слово привет отправляет войс.

Comment: Попробуйте `res = re.match("\bпривет\b", message.text, re.i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strings: list[str] = message.text.split()
for string in strings:
    if 'привет' in string.lower():
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="И тебе привет")
        break
```

Думаю можно сделать так